# Can I disable "mute" in Gmail video chat?

Tags: gmail, video, mute

I really like to use the video chat built in to Gmail to let my baby son and my grandma talk to each other. The problem is that he really likes to get up close to the camera and "type" on the keyboard of the laptop at the same time. I wouldn't mind this, except hitting "space" while in full screen mode switches on the mute mode, which makes it hard for the adults to talk at the same time.

Any technical fixes?

Comment: Pop off the spacebar key?

Comment: Put the keyboard away from the front of the computer? (Of course, assuming you are using a desktop computer, not a laptop.)

Comment: Or you could use a keyboard locker. There are some 3rd party solutions both for Windows and Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Google has disabled the keyboard shortcut for muting a video call using the spacebar, so I don't believe this is going to be too much of a problem now.

I can suggest, however, is to lock the keyboard if you are on the video call, which prevents toddlers from accidentally pressing on any keyboard buttons while on the video call, but you can try other ways of preventing the toddler from messing around with the keyboard though.